# UPDATE from two INNER JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I want to update a column in table `INVENTAR` from a couple of INNER JOINS.
I have the following:
Table `INVENTAR` with the column `PRODUCT_ID`,`CATEGORY` 
Table `PRODUCT_TO_CATEGORY` with the columns `PRODUCT_ID`,`CATEGORY_ID`
Table `CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION` with the columns `CATEGORY_ID`, `NAME`

I want the `NAME` column to update the `CATEGORY` column.
Here's my code:

```
UPDATE inventar
   SET inventar.category=category_description.name
  FROM inventar
       INNER JOIN product_to_category 
             ON product_to_category.product_id=inventar.product_id
       INNER JOIN category_description 
             ON category_description.category_id=product_to_category.category_id
```

Comment: Do you have any questions?

Comment: Well, it doens't work.. so I was hoping somebody would reformat the code..

Comment: I get this error: " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM inventar INNER JOIN product_to_category ON product_t' at line 3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct MySQL syntax is:

```
UPDATE inventar i INNER JOIN
       product_to_category ptc
       ON ptc.product_id = i.product_id INNER JOIN
       category_description cd
       ON cd.category_id = ptc.category_id
   SET i.category = cd.name;
```

Your syntax looks more appropriate for SQL Server or Postgres.